# MySQL Trigger: Insert into a new table with an IF statement but getting duplicates

Tags: mysql

I'm using an app called DataLoader which allows me to copy records from a view into a table. The app is configured to only update TableA if there's a new record or if there's a change to the date column.

I now need to send an email notification whenever there's a change to the date.

I created another table and i'm using a trigger to insert the records from TableA into TableB ONLY if there's a change to the date in TableA. I then have a script running to that compares TableA and TableB and sends an email if the records date has changed.

This works fine however, i'm getting duplicates whenever the DataLoader does an update. Whenever the DataLoader does an update, i'm getting tons and tons of duplicates. If i search for that same record in the view, there's no duplicates. There's also no duplicates in TableA.

If i manually change the date of a record in TableA, i do not get duplicates in TableB.

Why am i getting duplicates with the trigger below.

```
BEGIN
IF (NEW.Detail_ShipDate > OLD.Detail_ShipDate AND NEW.ShipVia='RI' ) THEN
    INSERT INTO nextgenorders2
        (`Order_Number` , `d_Detail_ShipDate` , `New_Detail_ShipDate` , `ShipTo_Name` , `Serial` , `Item` , `Item_Description` , `ShipVia` , `Rep_Name` , `EnteredBy` , `AssignedPerson` , `Status` ) 
    VALUES 
        (NEW.Order_Number, OLD.Detail_ShipDate, NEW.Detail_ShipDate, NEW.ShipTo_Name, NEW.Serial, NEW.Item, NEW.Item_Description, NEW.ShipVia, NEW.Rep_Name, NEW.EnteredBy, NEW.AssignedPerson, NEW.Status);
END IF;
END
```

Comment: Please, anyone?

Comment: Please provide some sample data for the scenario. It is unclear to make out right now.

Comment: Your trigger looks like it should do what you describe. Could you clarify what you mean by duplicate? Do you get duplicate rows in your table `nextgenorders2` if the date changes once, do you get duplicate mails (e.g. two mails for one date change) or do you get (non-duplicate) mails even though the date didn't actually change? Could you check if `d_Detail_ShipDate` , `New_Detail_ShipDate` in your table are all different and add some sample rows that caused incorrect duplicate mails? My prime suspect would be your DataLoader app, it might work differently than you expect.

Comment: I agree trigger looks fine (and tests fine for me) which suggests problem is elsewhere maybe shipdate is datetime and data loader is firing in loads of slightly different datetimes.